# Is down-casting within block parameters a bad practice?

Tags: objective-c, ios

As an example, instead of writing this:

```
NSArray *someArray = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4"];
[someArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSString *aString = obj;
    // do something
}];
```

You can down-cast the object directly if you know  the constants in the block method to make it more consice:

```
[someArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *aString, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // do something
}];
```

Does this go against any best practices or oop principles?

Comment: Note that just like in the case of `void *`, you don't have to cast `id`. `NSString *aString = obj;` is just fine.

Comment: OMG! Revelation! I will definitely be using this in the future!

Comment: @H2CO3 ah good point. I'll update the question for clarity

Comment: @EdwinIskandar See [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) as well.

Comment: @EdwinIskandar I bet up until this time you had been doing terrible things like `char *str = (char *)malloc(size + 1);` ;-)

Comment: @EdwinIskandar Yep :P It's a typical beginner problem. Most beginners do not care about style, and "if it works it's more than perfect". In fact, readability, clarity and overall style is very important (I'd say it makes up about 25-30% of the overall code quality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's fine. As long as you know what's in the array, feel free to statically type the `id` arguments. It's mostly syntactic sugar at the end of the day anyways. I always statically type anything I can. It helps me catch bugs as well as makes things easier to read. Also, as H2CO3 pointed out, objects can be assigned to an `id` and back without casts.

Comment: I certainly hope it's fine, I do it all the time.

Comment: I do it all the time as well, it tells the compiler what the objects are going to be and serves as documentation for myself later on.